# I Want to Launch Visual Studio on D Drive

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Unlike what most people are going through to get Visual Studio off of their system drive, I was able to put Visual Studio on my D drive, mostly by accident.

I ended up doing this because I had installed Windows 10 on a shiny, brand new solid state drive, making my old C drive my new D drive.

The problem is that I can't find where to launch Visual Studio because that the actual application is deeply hidden inside numerous files and such. Even a start menu search given nothing helpful.

I'd either like to find and delete every single file associated with Visual Studio so that I could reinstall it, or find the actual application and launch it from the D drive.

Comment: There's a search box in Windows 10, right next to the *start menu*. You can try using it.

Comment: so you did not install it - you put in a new drive reinstalled windows and just pluged in your old one as D: now right? In this case you should just reinstall - if not and it's indeed only a missing shortcut then just look in your installation folder (or search your filesystem) for `msdev` - also: AFAIK no matter what you do most of the files for VS will end up in your programm (x86) folder - so chances are high that you will not really move it away from C: :D

Comment: Well I thought of searching up "Start Menu" in the D drive. Turns out I need to reinstall, so I have to find every VS file I could so I can delete it.